# How do I fix a 429 API request error in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working with an API (I am noob at API's) and after some time I got this error  `"Request was throttled. Expected available in 82248 seconds."` This is a really important project I am working on and I didn't know there was a possibility for this to happen (lesson learned ). I can't wait that long to make a request again, is there another way to regain access to the API? Maybe activating a VPN or something like that? Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: I think you have a problem with the request to the API itself, show how you are addressing the API and where

Comment: This totally depends on the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP error 429 means that sent too many requests within a minute to the server, and the server assumes you either do not know what you are doing and/or doing a DOS attack. Servers usually do this to make sure it can continue to work with other clients. See more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

To solve your problem, just stop sending request on the server for couple of seconds (may be a minute depending how much you sent in the past minute. And it will work again. Rate limit may be implemented on the server globally, on a specific endpoint, or on a resource - check the API documentation for more details, [here is a facebook example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/).

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation , I think in my case it says that i have to wait 82248 seconds so it's like 22hours :/ so in order to regain access i will have to wait 22hours ?

Comment: yes, it all depends on the server policy - usually rate limits are per minute, but it can varies. There is nothing you can do about it.